Why is asking about how Christians should feel about something suitable for this site?
The question Since it's no longer Paul who sins, but rather sin living in him that does the sinning, should he feel any guilt or shame, any need to confess? doesn't ask about the meaning of the cited scripture.
Rather, it assumes several denominational doctrines and then asks what other Christians "should" feel:

Therefore should born again believers ever feel any guilt or shame, or any need to confess and apologize for sins that we don't commit … ?

That kind of question is very explicitly defined as off-topic:

Questions are on topic if they are focused on the text, rather than things to which the text may apply.
— What topics can I ask about here?.

Yet this question starts by stating (not asking) what the text means ("In Romans 7:17 and 20 Paul teaches us that …"), and then asks how Christians should apply that assumed meaning ("Therefore should … ?").
An existing question about the same scripture, Is Romans 7:17,20 excusing the true believer from weakness which leads to sin?,
asks about the meaning of the text, not about how to apply a presumed meaning to our personal lives.
Why am I the only one that thinks this question is unsuitable for this site?

The OP is asking about the interpretation (that is to say the practical consequence to the devout believer) of the text. Therefore the hermeneutic methodology has been defined by the OP within the question. The question (at this time) has five up-votes and no down-votes which is a measure of the community's response.

@NigelJ says "The OP is asking about the interpretation … of the text.".  No, it is asking about its application (what people should feel). See the explicit rule against this that I just added.

@NigelJ says "The question (at this time) has five up-votes and no down-votes". Exactly.  That's why I'm asking why I am the only one that sees this as a very blatant violation of what's allowed here.  (I'm not saying it is a bad question, just that it is explicitly unsuitable for this site as currently worded.) ¶ Compare it with the existing question Is Romans 7:17,20 excusing the true believer from weakness which leads to sin?.

Someone in the UK was prosecuted for moving their car forward at a traffic light, across the white line, to allow an ambulance to pass. They were fined for breaking The Law of the Traffic Light. But Jesus said 'the sabbath was made for man, not man for the sabbath'. And traffic lights were made for human safety, not human safety for traffic lights. And SE-BH was made to edify and instruct the users through voted-up questions. Not users made to uphold the Law of the Question.

I'd be inclined to agree with you, Ray - as you say, it feels wholly focused on contemporary application.
If I were in your shoes, I'd perhaps work talk to the author about it or go and suggest an Edit that refocuses the application on the original audience - in light of Paul's instructions what would be the application to them, and that would be helpful to the author and the community, rather than just closing it on something of a technicality. I'm a big fan of closing Off-Topic questions, but especially with newer users it's better to find a supportive way to intervene and help them get where they're trying to go, if it's permissible within the bounds of the site.

Agreed, but despite my comments indicating why it wasn't suitable, the OP made no changes, the question received 5 up-votes, no one other than I voted to close it, and 6 other people supplied answers to what to me seems like a blatantly badly worded question. And of those 6 people that answered, 4 have reputations in the thousands, and 2 in the tens of thousands. And if it were reworded to remove the inappropriate parts, what would be left is a fundamental question that would be a duplicate. The whole thing just feels really strange to me.


Why is asking about how Christians should feel about something suitable for this site?

Because the intent and sense of that question are not necessarily prescriptive or going beyond what the Bible provides. An answer can be premised on the Bible to discuss the compatibility (or incompatibility, accordingly) between Paul's denial of mens rea in Romans 7:17-20 and the other concepts the OP mentioned.
The language "should feel" is arguably flawed, but the OP's specific reference of the Bible makes up for that error: The reference conveys the essentials of what the OP is seeking. In line with Steve's central point, an answer that specifies the sense in which the language "should feel" here is meaningful in Hermeneutics is more constructive (also less alienating) than closing the question.
